# How to change the color of bar chart in Pentaho Report designer based on the value

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

I have a simple requirement wherein I would like to change the color of the bar chart in Pentaho report designer based on the value of y-axis. In case the number is negative, I would like to show it as a red bar, in case the value is positive, I would like to show this as a green bar.

I took a look at the following example but the color changes based on the values proximity to a goal of 1 million. I am pretty new to bean shell scripting and would really appreciate any inputs on the same: http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2011/05/dynamic-coloring-of-prd-charts/#downloads

Thank you,
Malavika